# Conditional expectation of X given Y

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider the random experiment in which three fair dice are rolled simultaneously (and independently). 
Let X be the random variable defined as the sum of the values of these three dice. 
Let $Y_1$ be the maximum of the three values, let $Y_2$ be their product, and let $Y=Y_1+Y_2$. 
Finally, define Z=[X∣∣Y] (the conditional expectation of X given Y).

Find the expected value of the random variable Z. Enter your answer as a fraction, such as $\frac{3}{2}$.